# JDBC SQLException Incorrect string value for UUID using JPA GenerationType.UUID

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, uuid

With Spring Boot 2, I was using Hibernate's @Type annotation for my UUID:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID id;
```

This worked for MySQL column `id varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL`.

However, when I upgraded my application to Spring Boot 3 with `jakarta.persistence`, it no longer works with the following code changes:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID id;
```

The error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x83\xE2\x19\xACF\x0B...' for column 'id' at row 1
```

The table has this encoding:

```
CREATE TABLE `application` (...) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I tried to create a simple todo application with the ff database information:

```
show create schema todo_db;

CREATE DATABASE `todo_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */

show create table todo;

CREATE TABLE `todo` (
`id` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
`status` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

While my connection in Spring Boot is:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo_db?serverTimezone=Asia/Manila&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

I am getting the same error.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Perhaps that string is already 16 binary bytes, not 36 ascii characters?  Can you check its length?

Comment: @RickJames, you are right. `BINARY(16)` works. But it is annoying since it is not readable if you view it using db viewer (e.g. Workbench). How do I make it work using `VARCHAR(36)`?

Comment: Leave off the hex2bin().